# Ionic2 ngFor in view not updating

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, ionic3

I have list of elements in my app, printing them out within *ngFor.
When the app is resumed I call a method to load new elements from the server by doing a http-Request. 
Inside this method I set the items as elements of the array.

However the array is not updated in the view. If i do a pull-to-refresh (on which I call the same method) the elements in the view are updated.

I tried wrapping the part of my code, that overrides the the old array in ngZone's `.run()` or a `setTimeout()` but nothing worked. Also tried with `ChangeDetectorRef`, also without success.

Now i am out of any ideas...

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
this.zone.run(() =>{
   this.posts = posts; // "posts" is the array of elements i got from http-request
                       // "this.posts" the array for the view
});
```

and also

```
setTimeout(() => {
   this.posts = posts;
}, 10);
```

and

```
this.posts = posts;
this.changedetectorRef.detectChanges(); //also tried markForCheck()
```

**MY CODE:**

view:

```
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let post of posts" >
    <ion-item>
        <p>{{post.newdistance}}</p>
    </ion-item>
</ion-item-sliding>
```

corresponding .ts file:

```
loadPosts() {
  let loading = this.loadingController.create({
    content: "Einen Moment bitte...",
    spinner: "crescent"
  });

  loading.present();

  this.postsService.getPostsFromServer().then(posts => {

    posts.forEach((post, index) => {

        this.geolocationService.getDistance(post.latitude, post.longitude).then(distance => {
            post.newdistance = distance;
        });

    });

    this.posts = posts; // <---- what to do here ???
    loading.dismiss();

  })
  .catch(() => {
    loading.dismiss();
  });
}
```

PLEASE help me!

**UPDATE**

When i put an alert and compare the old post value with the new one, both are updated. The problem is definitely the not-updating view

**UPDATE 2**

I noticed, when I add a button to the view on which i call the same function, the view is updated also...it just isn't updated when i resume the app...

Comment: can you show please more code.

Comment: *the app is resumed* you mean user switch between apps?

Comment: @Duannx yes, or if the user opens the application from background again

Answer (score 0):

The `this.posts = posts;` part of your code is executed *possibly before* the

```
this.geolocationService.getDistance(post.latitude, post.longitude).then(distance => {
            post.newdistance = distance;
        });
```

I say "*possibly before*", because it is a promise, you cannot be sure when exactly it will return.
So the newdistance value is set *after* you assign the `posts` to `this.posts`.

The best way to dealing with this is To chain your promise methods to be executed one after the other, not in parallel.

Another (more simple way) is to push each `post` into `this.posts` only after it has gotten the newdistance value.
**Keep in mind** that you should use a **new array** to push the posts, like this:

```
  //at the top of you page declare a new postsArray variable
  postsArray = [];
  this.postsService.getPostsFromServer().then(posts => {

    posts.forEach((post, index) => {

        this.geolocationService.getDistance(post.latitude, post.longitude).then(distance => {
            post.newdistance = distance;
            // Here we push the new post into the posts array
            this.postsArray.push(post);
        });

    });

    loading.dismiss();

  })
  .catch(() => {
    loading.dismiss();
  });
```

Comment: if i use a _new array_, which one do i reference in the view? Or when do i put the content of the _new array_ in `this.posts` ?

Comment: i just removed the `geolocationService` part, but all other properties of a post object dont update on the view also...just if i do a pull to refresh it works fine...im so confused

Comment: In your view you hould reference to `this.postsArray` instead of `this.posts`
Did you try it the way I proposed? Can you paste your latest code again?

Comment: Also, after stating that it works with the button you added, Are you sure that the method is called when the app is resumed? Did you put a console.log statement in the method to be sure that it is called?